Предлоги при приложении
Могут ли при приложении встретиться предлоги? Если есть предлог при слове, может ли это слово не быть приложением?

Мой покой остался в райском саду, в Эдеме.

Сочетание " в Эдеме" все же будет приложением или обстоятельством?

Мой покой остался в райском саду, в Эдеме.
Обособленное приложение или обстоятельство? Я считаю, что обстоятельство, а решение представляется мне таким.

Приложение — это определение, выраженное существительным, при этом  оно  относится к слову с предметным значением, например:

Это был (что?) райский сад (какой?) Эдем.  Я думаю (о чем?) о райском саде (о каком именно) об Эдеме.
Также при обособлении: Это был (что?) райский сад, (какой именно?) Эдем.  Я думаю (о чем?) о райском саде, (о каком именно?) об Эдеме.
Если определяемое слово является подлежащим или дополнением,то есть имеет предметное значение), то название сада будет приложением.  При этом наличие предлога не влияет на решение.

Мой покой остался в райском саду, (где именно?) в Эдеме. В саду — обстоятельство, то есть обозначает обстоятельственной признак места и относится к глаголу. Соответственно, в Эдеме также является уточняющим обстоятельством места.
Обстоятельство — это второстепенный член предложения, 
который относится к слову со значением действия или 
признака и  обозначает качественные и количественные 
характеристики этого действия или признака (способ 
осуществления действия, степень интенсивности действия 
или проявления признака), а также различные внешние 
обстоятельства осуществления действия (время, причину, 
условие и т.д.)



